# Python-Tkinter: Remove and create function labelframes in one click

Tags: python, tkinter

This code requires two presses after the first button has been selected. 
1 to clear the old labelframe and re-config the buttons, 
2 to create the new frame.

Can you please make it function in one click.

I'm switching between frames in one click. I only want the corresponding button's frame open at one time.

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.state('zoomed')

def remove_frame(lf):
    lf.destroy()
    a.config(command=A1)
    b.config(command=A2)
    c.config(command=A3)
def A1():
    a.configure(relief=SUNKEN,state=DISABLED)
    b.configure(relief=RAISED,state=ACTIVE)
    c.configure(relief=RAISED,state=ACTIVE)
    lf=LabelFrame(root,text='one')
    lf.pack()
    e=Button(lf,text='one')
    e.pack()
    b.config(command=lambda: remove_frame(lf))
    c.config(command=lambda: remove_frame(lf))
def A2():
    a.configure(relief=RAISED,state=ACTIVE)
    b.configure(relief=SUNKEN,state=DISABLED)
    c.configure(relief=RAISED,state=ACTIVE)
    lf=LabelFrame(root,text='two')
    lf.pack()
    e=Button(lf,text='two')
    e.pack()
    a.config(command=lambda: remove_frame(lf))
    c.config(command=lambda: remove_frame(lf))
def A3():
    a.configure(relief=RAISED,state=ACTIVE)
    b.configure(relief=RAISED,state=ACTIVE)
    c.configure(relief=SUNKEN,state=DISABLED)
    lf=LabelFrame(root,text='three')
    lf.pack()
    e=Button(lf,text='three')
    e.pack()
    a.config(command=lambda: remove_frame(lf))
    b.config(command=lambda: remove_frame(lf))

l=LabelFrame(root,padx=30,pady=20)
l.pack(padx=0,pady=18)

a=Button(l,text="1",command=A1)
a.grid(row=0,column=1)
b=Button(l,text="2",command=A2)
b.grid(row=0,column=2)
c=Button(l,text="3",command=A3)
c.grid(row=0,column=3)
d=Button(l, text="4",command=root.quit)
d.grid(row=0,column=4)

mainloop()
```

Comment: You can call the `destroy` method on a widget to remove it. Have you tried that?

Comment: I've been stuck for a week on this. Researched .destroy for 2.5h today but don't understand how to implement. Could you please share?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you even attempt to use `destroy`. Also, do you want to completely destroy it, or just hide it so that you can show it again later?

Comment: I have updated the question and code to make it simpler. I'm trying to switch between frames in one click. I only want the corresponding button's frame open at a time. I appreciate your responses, Bryan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pradepghr answered Jun 26 '17 at 16:42

"You can simply use lambda like this:"
`self.testButton = Button(self, text=" test", command=lambda:[funct1(),funct2()])`

Solution was stop the config in remove_frame and add multiple binds to original functions.

```
def remove_frame(lf):
    lf.destroy()
    # a.config(command=A1)
    # b.config(command=A2)
    # c.config(command=A3)
def A1():
    a.config(relief=SUNKEN,state=DISABLED)
    b.config(relief=RAISED,state=ACTIVE)
    c.config(relief=RAISED,state=ACTIVE)
    lf=LabelFrame(root,text='one')
    lf.pack()
    e=Button(lf,text='one')
    e.pack()

    b.config(command=lambda:[remove_frame(lf),A2()])
    c.config(command=lambda:[remove_frame(lf),A3()])
```